# summary {Hmisc} drops category?

Tags: r, crosstab

I am trying to get a crosstab with percentages from [this file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1791181/hmisc.csv) using `Hmisc`. But why is `summary()` dropping a category ("OTHERS") from the variable OCCUPATION?

```
library(Hmisc)
summary(ID ~ OCCUPATION, data=df, method="reverse")
```

Output:
Descriptive Statistics by ID

```
+--------------------------+--------+--------+
|                          |HUSBAND |SELF    |
|                          |(N=28)  |(N=72)  |
+--------------------------+--------+--------+
|OCCUPATION : SELF EMPLOYED|93% (26)|31% (22)|
+--------------------------+--------+--------+
```

Compare this to the simple `table()`

```
        OCCUPATION
ID        OTHERS SELF EMPLOYED
  HUSBAND      2            26
  SELF        50            22
```

Comment: I think something funky happens when print summary method calls `formatCats`. I'll try and get back to this a little later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is for the benefit of whoever has faced this peculiar problem. I stumbled across the solution after going over the very, very long documentation that `Hmisc` has. The solution is to use `print()` with `exclude1=F` option:

```
print(summary(ID ~ OCCUPATION, data=df, method="reverse"), exclude1=F)



Descriptive Statistics by ID

+-------------------+--------+--------+
|                   |HUSBAND |SELF    |
|                   |(N=28)  |(N=72)  |
+-------------------+--------+--------+
|OCCUPATION : OTHERS| 7% ( 2)|69% (50)|
+-------------------+--------+--------+
|    SELF EMPLOYED  |93% (26)|31% (22)|
+-------------------+--------+--------+
```